# Nonvanishing $g_{00}$ metric component in isotropic coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I have obtained a numerical solution to the Einstein's equations using the isotropic metric ansatz

$$ds^2=-e^{f(r)}\,dt^2+e^{g(r)}\left(dr^2+r^2\,d\Omega^2\right).$$

The associated energy density function is always positive in the interval $\left(M_{BH}/2, \infty\right)$ and I have imposed the condition that it vanishes at the horizon, $r=M_{BH}/2$. It turns out that the resulting $g_{00}$ component of the metric does not vanish at this point. With this, I have several questions:

1. What does it mean if the $g_{00}$ component of the isotropic coordinate does not vanish at the $r=M_{BH}/2$?
2. How do we define an event horizon in isotropic coordinates?

Comment: Event horizon means $g_{00}=0$. Have your tried to reproduce with your numerical procedure the metric of Schwarzschild's interior solution (constant energy density)?

Comment: The horizon is generally at $g^{\rm rr}=0$, but in spherical symmetric metrics like Schwarzschild where in  [isotropic coordinates](http://relativity.yukterez.net/43.html#transformation) $g_{\rm tt}=\rm [(M-2\hat{r})/(M+2\hat{r})]$ the $g_{\rm tt}$ also does vanish at the horizon at $\rm \hat{r}=M/2$, or in classical Schwarzschild reduced circumference coordinates where $\rm r=\hat{r} [1+M/(2\hat{r})]^2 $ at $ 
 \rm r=2M$, so your premise is wrong.

Comment: If you take Schwarzschild interior solution for $8/9 \le \alpha \le 1$ ($\alpha=r_{S}/R) $ then the event horizon (EH) is defined by $g_{00}=0$ resulting in $r_{EH}=R \sqrt{9-8/\alpha}$. The corresponding metric component $g^{rr}$ is non zero being equal to $9 (1-\alpha)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: I am using here canonical (Schwarzschild) coordinates.

Comment: @Christoffel Something is wrong about your boundary condition. Maybe you should look in that [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258351868_Some_Exact_General_Relativistic_Compact_Perfect_Fluid_Spheres_in_Isotropic_Coordinates) to see what are proper boundary conditions.